# Why does android.graphics.DashPathEffect double interval distances?

Tags: android, android-canvas

The following code draws from the start of my path to halfway through my path when animatedProgressPercentage = 0f and as it reaches 1f, it will nearly reach the end.

```
dashPathEffect = new DashPathEffect( new float[]{
    new PathMeasure(path, false).getLength()/4f, // length of intervals 'on' 
    aVeryLargeNumber}, // length of intervals 'off' 
    0f - (pathLength/2f)*animatedProgressPercentage); // offset length to start (aka phase)
paint.setPathEffect(dashPathEffect);
```

When I switch the `/4f` to `/8f` half becomes a quarter. My question is, why isn't `/4f` drawing a quarter of the path? Why do I need to divide pathLength by two in the phase? And why does it only nearly reach the end instead of the whole thing?

I'm also doing this

```
viewRect.set(0, 0, w, h);
m.setRectToRect(boundsRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
path.transform(m);
```

but using `scale = viewRect.width() / boundsRect.width();` as a multiplier didn't seem to help at all. Maybe I've completely misunderstood the intended usage of DashPathEffect or maybe I need to show more code here to be understood myself? Please let me know!